# Code a directory structure from scratch (imaginary files / folders etc.) in python?

Tags: python, file, structure, directory

#### **Tell me if this has already been answered!!!**

### **Background info:**

Hello, I am Max, 14 years old and from Germany.
Currently I am working on the mechanic for a little game I want to code in Python,   just to learn the language and get comfortable with it. In The game you have to find and delete a imaginary "virus" on a "computer". To do so, you have to navigate through folders and execute a couple of commands, just like you would in the normal terminal.

### **Actual Question:**

My Problem is navigating through directories. I might not have the best method of setting up the structure and I also don't really know a better way of doing it. Maybe anyone here has an idea. I don't really want to use real folders and just access them from my programm, since I really want to learn the language.
I will provide you with the code, that is necessary.

I have a list (as seen below), that contains all the commands my programm accepts at the moment and a second one that contains the number of attributes every individual comment requires. These attributes are in a third list, where they can be reached by the index of the command itself, thats what the variable, "index" is.

```
comm = ['hello', 'help', 'cd', 'ls', 'cdir', 'rdir', 'cfil', 'rfil', 'detc']
commAtt = ['0', '0', '1', '1', '2', '2', '2', '2', '1']
attribute = ['0', '0', '* directory *', '* directory *', '* directory *  * new name *',
         '* directory *  * new name *', '* file path *  * new name *',
         '* file path *  * new name *', '* malware / spamware / adware *']


# Directories
total = 7
layer0 = ['Boot']
# layer1
Boot = ['System', 'Users', 'Applications']
#layer2
System = ['Library', 'System files']
Users = ['Phillipp Dorson', 'Root']
Applications = ['Corel .exe', 'Text Editor.exe', 'Python lib', 'Internet.exe']
# layer3
PhillippD = ['Documents', 'Downloads', 'Pictures', 'Movies', 'Desktop',
                 'Music']
# layer4
Documents = ['Job_Application.txt', 'Cover_Page.corel']

def dirCheck(command, path, index):
count = 0
layerI = 'null'
dir = layerI
for pathI in range(0, len(path) - 1):
    print(pathI)
    for layerI in layer0:
        dir = layerI
        if path[pathI] == layerI:
            print('hellu')
            break
        else:
            count += 1
            break

    print(dir)
    for layerI in dir:
        print(layerI)
        if path[pathI] == layerI:
            print('lulloooo')
            break
        else:
            count += 1
```

As you can probably see, I am currently trying to use a variable(dir) for another variable (acctually the arrays, that contain the files and folders like "Boot[]" or "Documents[]"), which doesn't seem to work very well. I tried to avoid typing all of the list individually, however if it isn't possible to do it differently, I will.
***Thanks in advance, Max.***

#### Edit:

As suggested by @rczajka, I made the file structure with a dictionary. However I still don't quite get how I should loop trough this 'system', to check if the input is valid, for example, since I have to loop through a dictionary inside of a dictionary inside of a dictionary and so on. This is, what I came up with so far:

```
directories = {
'Boot': {
    'System': {
        'Library': {}
    },
    'Users': {

    },
    'Applications': {

    }
}
```

}

```
for i in directories:      #layer 1
    print(i)
    for a in directories[i]:      #layer 2
        print(a)
        for b in directories[i][a]:      #layer 3
            print(b)
```

It does work, but I have to type a new loop for every 'layer' of files. I don't really like that idea since it limits the amounts of folders you can have inside other folders, if you know what I mean.
I would really appreciate some help from you guys! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Technically, you *can* access a variable by its name, by using things like `locals()` or `globals()`, but this isn't the normal way to do it.

Normally you would define your imaginary directories as a data structure and then look for a way for your code to navigate it. So you could start with something like this:

```
imaginary_tree = {
    'Boot': {
        'System': {
            'Library': { ... },
            'System files': { ... }
        },
        'Users': {
            'Phillipp Dorson': { ... },
            'Root': { ... },
        },
        ...
    }
}
```

Then you'll need to see how your code can maintain a *current path*, so the user can go up and down the hierarchy, and also how to differentiate your imaginary files from imaginary directories.

Hope this points you in the right direction, have fun!

---

**edit:**

To iterate through such structure, you can use recursion, like:

```
def print_directory(directory):
    for subdir in directory:
        print(subdir)
        print_directory(directory[subdir])
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This acctually helped me a lot already. However I still have some problems lopping through the dictionaries inside of dictionaries inside of dictionaries etc. I edited my original question so I would really appreciate you to have a look and see if you can help me out again.

Comment: I've added a simple recursive function to my answer to show you how you can iterate over such a structure.